# Updating values in a compute shader through CommandBuffer in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, compute-shader

I'm trying to update a couple of floats and a vector in a [CommandBuffer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.CommandBuffer.html).

```cs
var clickTypeLocation = Shader.PropertyToID("ClickType");
drawPipelineBuilder.computePipeline.SetComputeFloatParam(compute, clickTypeLocation, mouse1 ? UNSET : SET);

var mouseRadiusPowLocation = Shader.PropertyToID("MouseRadiusPow");
drawPipelineBuilder.computePipeline.SetComputeFloatParam(compute, mouseRadiusPowLocation, Mathf.Pow(mouseRadius, 2));

var mousePosLocation = Shader.PropertyToID("MousePos");
drawPipelineBuilder.computePipeline.SetComputeVectorParam(compute, mousePosLocation, mousePos);
```

The SetComputeXParam functions only takes values and not references, and therefore will be the same everytime i do `Graphics.ExecuteCommandBuffer(drawPipeline);` later in my code. Is there a way around this other than simply avoiding the CommandBuffer i.e using `compute.SetFloat` just before executing CommandBuffer?